# C++ Error C2280 - Attempting to Reference a Deleted Function - On Primitive Types

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, stdtuple

I'm implementing my own two unordered maps, one that takes in a key that is a tuple with 3 arguments, and another that is a tuple with 2 arguments. The following is my code:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

#include <unordered_map>
#include <tuple>

namespace Valk::ExchangeGateway::TupleMap
{
    using boost::hash_value;
    using boost::hash_combine;
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto hashTuple = [](const std::tuple<T, U>& singleTuple) -> size_t
    { 
        size_t seed{}; 
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<0>(singleTuple)));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<1>(singleTuple)));
        return seed;
    };
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto equalTuple = [](const std::tuple<T, U>& firstTuple, const std::tuple<T, U>& secondTuple) -> bool
    {
        return std::get<0>(firstTuple) == std::get<0>(secondTuple)
            && std::get<1>(firstTuple) == std::get<1>(secondTuple);
    };
    template <typename T, typename U, typename D>
    auto hashTripleTuple = [](const std::tuple<T, U, D>& singleTuple) -> size_t
    {
        size_t seed{};
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<0>(singleTuple)));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<1>(singleTuple)));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<2>(singleTuple)));
        return seed;
    };
    template <typename T, typename U, typename D>
    auto equalTripleTuple = 
            [](const std::tuple<T, U, D>& firstTuple, const std::tuple<T, U, D>& secondTuple) -> bool
    {
        return std::get<0>(firstTuple) == std::get<0>(secondTuple)
            && std::get<1>(firstTuple) == std::get<1>(secondTuple)
            && std::get<2>(firstTuple) == std::get<2>(secondTuple);
    };

    using InstrumentFrequency = int;
    using TotalDelta = double;

    using FutureTupleUnorderedMap = std::unordered_map<std::tuple<TotalDelta, Instrument::InstrumentID, Platform::Price>,
        InstrumentFrequency, decltype(hashTripleTuple<TotalDelta, Instrument::InstrumentID, Platform::Price>),
        decltype(equalTripleTuple<TotalDelta, Instrument::InstrumentID, Platform::Price>)>;

    using OptionTupleUnorderedMap = std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Platform::Quantity, Instrument::InstrumentID>,
        InstrumentFrequency, decltype(hashTuple<Platform::Quantity, Instrument::InstrumentID>),
        decltype(equalTuple<Platform::Quantity, Instrument::InstrumentID>)>;
}
```

All the typedefs you see, such as `Platform::Quantity` and `Platform::Price` are typedefs of primitive types, like `long long` or `int`.

For some reason, I get the following errors (screenshot is easier than copy and paste here), and I'm not sure why. There isn't a class here whose copy constructor is deleted or not generated.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can copy the full error messages - including additional info from the compiler - from the "output" tab.

Comment: Yup. Screenshot is illegible, not "easier". Also, it doesn't hurt to make it self-contained http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1b89eb824406927

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambdas aren't default constructable. So, you need to pass the hash/equality operators. Alternatively, you can derive a named type of the lambda and add default constructibility:

The simplest would be to combine the hash respectively equality ops for dual/triple tuples:

```
struct HashTuple {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator()(const std::tuple<T, U>& singleTuple) const -> size_t
    { 
        size_t seed{}; 
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<0>(singleTuple)));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<1>(singleTuple)));
        return seed;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U, typename D>
    auto operator()(const std::tuple<T, U, D>& singleTuple) const -> size_t
    {
        size_t seed{};
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<0>(singleTuple)));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<1>(singleTuple)));
        hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<2>(singleTuple)));
        return seed;
    }
};

struct EqualTuple {
    template <typename... T>
    auto operator()(const std::tuple<T...>& firstTuple, const std::tuple<T...>& secondTuple) const -> bool {
        return firstTuple == secondTuple;
    }
};
```

> Note this uses the equivalent `std::tuple::operator==` implementation

Now, you can simplify the types:

```
std::unordered_map<std::tuple<double, int, double>, int, HashTuple, EqualTuple>
std::unordered_map<std::tuple<unsigned int, int>, int, HashTuple, EqualTuple>
```

Which I'd summarize with a simple helper:

```
template <typename... Key> using FrequencyMap = 
    std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Key...>, InstrumentFrequency, HashTuple, EqualTuple>;

using FutureTupleUnorderedMap = FrequencyMap<TotalDelta, Instrument::InstrumentID, Platform::Price>;
using OptionTupleUnorderedMap = FrequencyMap<Platform::Quantity, Instrument::InstrumentID>;
```

Now we have a fully working demo:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/635650e17b776dab)**

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Instrument {
    using InstrumentID = int;
};
struct Platform {
    using Quantity = unsigned;
    using Price = double;
};

namespace Valk::ExchangeGateway::TupleMap {
    struct HashTuple {
        template <typename T, typename U>
        auto operator()(const std::tuple<T, U>& singleTuple) const -> size_t
        { 
            using boost::hash_value;
            using boost::hash_combine;
            size_t seed{}; 
            hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<0>(singleTuple)));
            hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<1>(singleTuple)));
            return seed;
        }

        template <typename T, typename U, typename D>
        auto operator()(const std::tuple<T, U, D>& singleTuple) const -> size_t
        {
            using boost::hash_value;
            using boost::hash_combine;
            size_t seed{};
            hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<0>(singleTuple)));
            hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<1>(singleTuple)));
            hash_combine(seed, hash_value(std::get<2>(singleTuple)));
            return seed;
        }
    };

    struct EqualTuple {
        template <typename... T>
        auto operator()(const std::tuple<T...>& firstTuple, const std::tuple<T...>& secondTuple) const -> bool {
            return firstTuple == secondTuple;
        }
    };

    using InstrumentFrequency = int;
    using TotalDelta = double;


    template <typename... Key> using FrequencyMap = 
        std::unordered_map<std::tuple<Key...>, InstrumentFrequency, HashTuple, EqualTuple>;

    using FutureTupleUnorderedMap = FrequencyMap<TotalDelta, Instrument::InstrumentID, Platform::Price>;
    using OptionTupleUnorderedMap = FrequencyMap<Platform::Quantity, Instrument::InstrumentID>;
}

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    {
        Valk::ExchangeGateway::TupleMap::FutureTupleUnorderedMap ftum;
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(ftum).name()) << "\n";
    }
    {
        Valk::ExchangeGateway::TupleMap::OptionTupleUnorderedMap otum;
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle(typeid(otum).name()) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints the type names you saw above.

Comment: For fun, here's a c++17 version that combines the hash into a single variadic function: https://godbolt.org/z/Hk473u (also [@lefticus approved](https://leighjohnston.files.wordpress.com/2019/10/3d2ltj1.jpg))

Comment: Wow, this explanation is amazing. Thank you so much for this. You too @sehe.

Comment: What does `el` stand for by the way in `HashTuple`?